# PHPMailer won't connect to Exchange 2010 with error message "Success"

Tags: phpmailer, exchange-server

Error Message:

```
2021-10-12 11:38:19 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success [/web/some/path/phpmailer6/src/SMTP.php line 471]
```

PHP Configuration:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
             'verify_peer' => false,
             'verify_peer_name' => false,
             'allow_self_signed' => true
         )
     );    
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host     = '192.168.123.123';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username = "some_user";
$mail->Password = "some_password";
```

- PHP Version is 5.6.40
- Sending via other, non-exchange Servers works
- There is a Connector for the specific IP on Exchange that allows TLS and standard AUTH.
- The Exchange supports TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2
- I've added the above SMTPOptions
- I tried downloading and setting a cafile path for openssl in the php.ini

Nothing seems to make any difference and the error message is simply not helpful at all.

Full error log:

```
2021-10-12 11:38:19 Connection: opening to 192.168.123.123:25, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
2021-10-12 11:38:19 Connection: opened
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "220 my.mailserver Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 12 Oct 2021 13:38:19 +0200"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 my.mailserver Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 12 Oct 2021 13:38:19 +0200
2021-10-12 11:38:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mydomain.com
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-my.mailserver Hello [192.168.123.123]"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH LOGIN"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-XEXCH50"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250-XRDST"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "250 XSHADOW"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-my.mailserver Hello [192.168.123.123]250-SIZE250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS250-AUTH LOGIN250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250-XEXCH50250-XRDST250 XSHADOW
2021-10-12 11:38:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready"
2021-10-12 11:38:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2021-10-12 11:38:19 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success [/web/some/path/phpmailer6/src/SMTP.php line 471]
```

What new things can I try?

Comment: It is an unhelpful message, but that's what PHP is returning. You definitely shouldn't be disabling certificate verification, but the biggest issue here is that you are writing new code to run on an ancient version of PHP from 2014 that contains a zillion known security holes. Fix that first.

Comment: Well, to upgrade the PHP version, I would need to single-handedly re-write around 3000 DB queries in this internal-only program first, unfortunately I'm stuck with spaghetti-code for the time being...

Comment: The PHP version you're running has nothing to do with database queries; That's up to your DB server. What's stopping you from upgrading to at least PHP 5.6.40, which is the same major version but 4 years newer?

Comment: Oh, it is 5.6.40, I will correct this information. The problem is the removal of mysql_ commands in PHP 7 and newer.

Comment: OK, that's not *quite* so bad! Next step would be to run some tests using the `openssl` command line tool to see what's going wrong with the connection, and whether it's an internal PHP problem. There are some details on doing that in the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: Exchange 2010 went end of life last year ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/exchange-2010-end-of-support?view=o365-worldwide#:~:text=Exchange%20Server%202010%20reached%20its,the%20time%20to%20start%20planning.)  You really shouldn't have this computer connected to a network.

Comment: Could you write a PHP 8.0 API for this one operation, and then connect to it in your PHP 5.6 app? I know that's more work, and it's a pain to sort out new deployment infra, but it would be easier than the rewrite you refer to.

Comment: PHP 5.6 is horribly outdated. Have you tried using a more common version?